# Laravel 5 'assertReponseOk' fails (gets 500 error) when I use Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, mockery

I'm trying to use mockery to write unit tests and it's working. However, there is one thing that doesn't work.

I've been looking for an answer for some days but I haven't found anything, so here is the thing. First I'll put a summarized version and then all the code.

**This doesn't work:**

```
public function testIndexCallsRepository()
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository');

    $mock->shouldReceive('getAll')->once();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getGenres')->once();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getCountries')->once();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getFormats')->once();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getEncodigs')->once();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getUbications')->once();

    App::instance('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository', $mock);

    $response = $this->call('GET', 'movies');

    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

When running phpunit, the last line of code gives me the this error:

```
Expected status code 200, got 500
```

The mocked class and assert methods (the shouldReceive_s) work fine. I have checked it by calling bad methods or removing the calls from the controller, although **mocking doesn't seem to have any effect when there is the response error**, as I only get the response error.

**If I remove the mocking code**, leaving only the response, **it works** (I do get a status code of 200 instead of 500), so I must be missing something.

I've been following some articles about mocking that include those two response lines **after the mocking**.

```
$this->call('GET', 'movies');
$this->assertResponseOk();
```

So it seems to be very basic stuff that works without problem. One of the articles I'm refering to is this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456.

I have also tried:

- writting '$this->app->instance' instead of 'App::instance' and putting it before the 'shouldReceive_s' with no effects.
- including 'parent::tearDown' in the tearDown method.

Any guess? What's wrong?

By the way, I'm currently doing a work-around:

- I put the mocked test without checking for a 'assertResponseOk', and have checked that the mocking is working as I said before.
- I have another method to check the response, if the view is getting the data and so on, without using mocks.

Here's the 'complete' code that fails. I haven't included the repository code. It works, the view display the data properly.

**Test code:**

```
class MovieControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testIndexCallsRepository()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository');

        $mock->shouldReceive('getAll')->once();
        $mock->shouldReceive('getGenres')->once();
        $mock->shouldReceive('getCountries')->once();
        $mock->shouldReceive('getFormats')->once();
        $mock->shouldReceive('getEncodigs')->once();
        $mock->shouldReceive('getUbications')->once();

        App::instance('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository', $mock);

        $response = $this->call('GET', 'movies');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }

    public function testIndexResponseIsOkAndViewHasAllTheData()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'movies');

        $this->assertResponseOk();

        $this->assertViewHas('movies');
        $this->assertViewHas('genre_options');
        $this->assertViewHas('country_options');
        $this->assertViewHas('format_options');
        $this->assertViewHas('encoding_options');
        $this->assertViewHas('ubication_options');

        $movies     = $response->original->getData()['movies'];
        $genres     = $response->original->getData()['genre_options'];
        $countries  = $response->original->getData()['country_options'];
        $formats    = $response->original->getData()['format_options'];
        $encodings  = $response->original->getData()['encoding_options'];
        $ubications = $response->original->getData()['ubication_options'];

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection', 
            $movies);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $genres);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $countries);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $formats);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $encodings);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $ubications); 
    }
}
```

**Controller code:**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository;

class MovieController extends Controller {

    protected $movie;

    public function __construct(IMovieRepository $movie)
    {
        $this->movie = $movie;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['movies']            = $this->movie->getAll();
        $data['genre_options']     = $this->movie->getGenres();
        $data['country_options']   = $this->movie->getCountries();
        $data['format_options']    = $this->movie->getFormats();
        $data['encoding_options']  = $this->movie->getEncodings();
        $data['ubication_options'] = $this->movie->getUbications();

        return view('movies.index', $data);
    }
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('movies', 'MovieController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that every mocking should return at least an empty array because otherwise you are assigning null to the array.

Comment: Have checked that in various ways (that is, returning different things). Also, in the tutorials/examples that I've followed there is no mention to such a thing. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without your view code, I can't be certain, but, I'm pretty sure you're code is breaking because your `movies.index` view is requiring that certain `$data` array keys can't be null. I would suggest one of the following:

### Circumvent View logic

```
public function testIndexCallsRepository()
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository');

    $mock->shouldReceive('getAll')->once()->andReturn('all');
    $mock->shouldReceive('getGenres')->once()->andReturn('genres');
    $mock->shouldReceive('getCountries')->once()->andReturn('countries');
    $mock->shouldReceive('getFormats')->once()->andReturn('formats');
    $mock->shouldReceive('getEncodigs')->once()->andReturn('encodings');
    $mock->shouldReceive('getUbications')->once()->andReturn('ubications');

    App::instance('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository', $mock);

    $expectedViewData = array(
         'movies' => 'movies',
         'genre_options' => 'genres',
         'country_options' => 'countries',
         'format_options' => 'formats',
         'encoding_options' => 'encodings',
         'ubication_options' => 'ubications',
    );

    View::shouldReceive('make')->once()->with('movies.index', $expectedViewData)->andReturn('compiled view'); 

    $response = $this->call('GET', 'movies');

    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

### Mock responses from repository

```
public function testIndexCallsRepository()
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository');

    $mock->shouldReceive('getAll')->once()->andReturn(array('all'));
    $mock->shouldReceive('getGenres')->once()->andReturn(array('genres'));
    $mock->shouldReceive('getCountries')->once()->andReturn(array('countries'));
    $mock->shouldReceive('getFormats')->once()->andReturn(array('formats'));
    $mock->shouldReceive('getEncodigs')->once()->andReturn(array('encodings'));
    $mock->shouldReceive('getUbications')->once()->andReturn(array('ubications'));

    App::instance('App\Repositories\Movie\IMovieRepository', $mock);

    $response = $this->call('GET', 'movies');

    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Above code is not tested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Have just read it. I've moved to other things but I'll give it a try. Thank you!